# Can you return a different object sent from a PUT request?

Tags: c#, rest, web-applications, put, raml

As the title says I am wondering if it possible to return information from the controller based on the success of the PUT request.

In this case I am using the put request to use my email service to send emails. Is there a way to return a results object that lists the statuses for each email so I can display on the front end which emails failed and why?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally PUT request(successful) is used to:

1.) Update an existing resource -200 OK with **NO response body**

2.) Creation of new resource (If the Request-URI does not point to an existing resource, origin server can create the resource with that URI) - **201 Created with some meta data ,resource identifier in the response body.**

So as per the recommendation ,it should not be returned in the response of PUT request and a subsequent GET call should be made to get the status of the emails.

Refer the HTTP specification :
RF2616 -https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6